# how can i get the getElementById value from the parent div?

Tags: javascript

```js
 setInterval(function(){
      var parent = document.getElementByClassName("b");
      var child = parent.children[1];
      var intext = child.innerHTML;
      var price = parseInt(intext.textContent.replace(/,/g,''));
      var beforecalf = price - 5000 ;
      var beforecals = price - 4000 ;
                                                
      if(document.getElementById("basic_0")) {
          bpricefirst = String(beforecalf).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
          bpricesecond = String(beforecals).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
          document.querySelector('#thislogin').textContent = bpricefirst;
          document.querySelector('#thisnotlogin').textContent = bpricesecond;
        }
        },1000);
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <span class="first">price :</span>
  <span class="second">25$</span>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <span class="first">price :</span>
  <span class="second">20$</span>
</div>

<div id="basic_0"> <!-- script will run if i have this #basic_0 div -->
</div>

<div id="thislogin"></div> 
<div id="thisnotlogin"></div>
```

what i try to do is bring the .second vlaue ($20) from the .b div box.
as you can see, div box which named a and b have exactly same class name inside. (fisrst, second)

in there, i have to bring the .second value from the .b div box not .a
so to make that, i used below code but it is not work.... :(

```
var parent = document.getElementByClassName("b");
  var child = parent.children[1];
  var intext = child.innerHTML;
  var price = parseInt(intext.textContent.replace(/,/g,''));
```

before i try this
i put like this

```
var price = parseInt(document.querySelector('.second').textContent.replace(/,/g,''));
```

but it brings 25$ value;;
to bring 20$ vlaue what do i have to change??

any help will be so appreciated! thanks!
*don't know reason, why it display as ""... but it is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz9SN.jpg) this;;

Comment: It's `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName` (Elements plural not Element singular)

Comment: Why not make `.b` part of your `querySelector`?

Comment: @lvar Hi! cause i need .second value from .b. if i set just .b then it bring .first either.

Comment: @geo_ I meant `document.querySelector('.b .second')`.

Comment: omg......@lvar ....omg... love you so much!!!! really thanks a lot!!!!! it is exactly what i want !!! i didn't know this way....wow... it is soooo simple than my thought....omg.....really thanks!!! have a great day!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myLI").parentElement.nodeName;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="myLI">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how to make this code work on my code?? cause as you can see in my code each a and b div box have same class name divs. so if i set "var x = document.getElementsByClassName("second").parentElement.nodeName;" then isn't it bring the both of a and b value??

Comment: Then you need to use getElementByClass instead getElementById. `var x = document.getElementByClassName("myLI").parentElement.nodeName;` It returns an object.